# Spring MVC calling existing third party SOAP Service with WSDL and Service Name

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am working on a Spring MVC project with Spring 4.3.2 (latest at this time).
We also use Spring Security 4.1.1 and Hibernate 5.01.  This back-end project is a set of RESTful API's.

Within the business login in our "services" layer, we want to call several third party SOAP Web-Services.   We actually DO have the WSDL files, and a service name from these outside SOAP web-services.  We do have the URL, and this URL is the location of the WSDL file, we have the username password.

I suppose this could be a standard java question on how to call/consume SOAP web-services, but since we are in the Spring world, I figure we want out code to be "Spring-ified."

I'll keep looking on the net, but most of the examples I have seen require a WSDL file we do not have at this point.

Any help would be much appreciated.   Thanks!

UPDATE:
I was looking at some old code we had with Seam, JBoss, and RichFaces.  There are a few API calls from Jboss/J2EE which we are removing.   It looks like we had a generic SOAP proxy which took a WSDL-URL string and a QName.  It looks like this old code had a FormSubmit and a FormSubmitResponse which was a class for a JAXB conversion to these objects.

So, provided I have the WSDL in a URL, and a known method name to call.  That should make my problem easier.

Comment: How do you know what operations are supported? Furthermore, how do you know what the input documents should look like (i.e. - I assume no schema either)?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the Web Service Stubs with Maven or Gradle (depending on what you are using)
Take a look at this example:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/